# Can I recover the replaced file by SVN in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using SVN as code repository. Accidentally I replaced my entire project with the one in SVN. As soon as I replaced, i tried to look at the local history of some files and figured out that there won't be any.

Is there anyway I can switch back my project (or atleast a file in that project) to previous versions in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

History is stored in this (hidden) folder:

.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/

So you should be able to restore from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the svn history. In Eclipse IDE (with subeclipse):

1. right click
2. show history
3. in the history window, locate the desired version (e.g. 55)
4. right click on it and Switch to Revision 55